# Does keycloak provide a way to distinguish between logins by the same user on different devices

Tags: keycloak

Does keycloak provide a way to distinguish between logins by the same user on different devices (a user can be logged in on mobile device/s and also on desktop browser/s).

Does keycloak provide a way to identify when a user entered their credentials (whether through keycloak login or using an identity provider flow)?

Our use case is:

- a user can request to reset their pin (from our app).
- the user is logged out (a `/logout` using the 'keycloak-connect'
  middleware).
- following logout, the user is redirected to login and enters
  credentials (keycloak or identity provider).
- on login, the user is presented with the 'enter a new pin' page (our app).

To achieve this we want to be able to determine server side when to send the 'enter a new pin' page.

Our situation is that we don't easily know (for various reasons, including active keycloak session or other token expire/active states) when an actual 'credentials entered' login occurs.

Could the `session_state` from the keycloak access token be used to identify which keycloak session a client request corresponds to?

Could something like the following work:

- the server receives the keycloak access token (containing the
  `session_state`) from the keycloak login,
- the server passes the `session_state` to the client (browser/mobile
  app),
- the client passes this `session_state` back to the server along with
  the user requesting the action,
- the server requests the session information from keycloak (something along the lines of making the following request to the admin REST API localhost:8080/auth/admin/realms/demo/users/{{user_id}}/sessions - then checking against `session_state` somehow?)
- if the 'start' value of the session returned by the REST API is
  recent, then maybe we have 'actual' login information?

We're still using Keycloak 6.0.1

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I wonder how this is related with keycloak at all. You tell the PIN reset happens entirely in your application, then why don't you mark that user with a flag and don't let him access any resource till the PIN gets reset? That flag could be related to a server session cookie (managed by your application), for the user to be able to use the application in other devices/browsers.

Comment: Thanks Biker. This was an approach we considered. I think I've found a solution using keycloak sessions, so I'll proceed with that. I'll come back to this option if I encounter other issues. Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: call Get :/auth/realms/develop/protocol/openid-connect/userinfo  with token in header

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to update with how I'm proceeding, which I believe gives me all I want in terms of solving/answering my original question.

The keycloak access token includes: "sub", "auth_time" and "session_state".

```
{
  "sub": "ae384e77-7588-444b-9c4f-3dc920750e1f",
  "auth_time": 1590555910,
  "session_state": "2d735372-1a5a-43de-8a6c-1a45deebf20b",
}
```

I can use the sub to query the Keycloak Admin REST API with `https://my-domain.com/auth/admin/realms/demo/users/{{sub}}/sessions` which gives a list like:

```
[

  {
    "id": "2d735372-1a5a-43de-8a6c-1a45deebf20b",
    "username": "20000",
    "userId": "ae384e77-7588-444b-9c4f-3dc920750e1f",
    "ipAddress": "52.62.57.52",
    "start": 1590555910000,
    "lastAccess": 1590555910000,
    "clients": {
      "4eb676c2-94c3-4bac-a423-94a7bf57ece0": "demo"
    }
  }
]
```

I can then choose from the returned sessions list matching the `id` to the `session_state` from the access token (n.b., that `start` from the sessions list matches `auth_time` from the access token.

This gives me what I need. I can pass the original session_state to the client and request from keycloak matching that session_state :)

I'll update if I encounter issues.